# Removing repeated zeros from vector

Tags: matlab

Let's say I have this vector:

```
A=[0 0 0 400 600 1000 1400 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 600 400 100 1000 0 0 0 0 400 600 1000 0 0];
```

How can you compress repeated zeros to at most two zeros in between non-zeros, and just one zero allowed at the ends? The output should be:

```
B=[0 400 600 1000 1400 0 0 600 400 100 1000 0 0 400 600 1000 0];
```

Comment: What is it exactly you're trying to accomplish? Your title suggests you want to find the most frequent number, but your question sounds like you want to find (the index of?) the last zero in the array.

Comment: Use `find` with option `last`

Comment: My question is I want to find last zero among the repeated zero number.

Comment: Please give the desired output.

Comment: Should be my output is
output:
0 400 600 1000 1400 0      
0 600 400 100 1000 0      
0 400 600 1000 0

Comment: It is not clear how that output is generated from the input. Can you describe the algorithm in plain language? It looks like you are compressing repeated zeros to at most two zeros in between non-zeros, and just one zero allowed at the ends.

Comment: ya chappjc.. it exactly like that. Sorry because I understand in different way.. read 0 between non-zero value.

Comment: OK, I think my answer (just added) performs as described above.

Comment: -1 as the Title, description and example seem to be three completely different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The apparent goal is to compress sequences of zeros occurring between non-zeros to at most just two zeros, and to just one zero for repeated zeros at the ends of vector. The example input/output given in the question is as follows.

Input:

```
A = [0 0 0 400 600 1000 1400 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 600 400 100 1000 0 0 0 0 400 600 1000 0 0];
```

Output:

```
B0 = [0 400 600 1000 1400 0 0 600 400 100 1000 0 0 400 600 1000 0];
```

This can be accomplished with the following statements:

```
dx = diff(A==0);
extraZeros = (A==0) & ~([dx==-1 0] | [0 dx==1]);
B = A(~extraZeros)
B =
  Columns 1 through 7
       0         400         600        1000        1400           0           0
  Columns 8 through 14
     600         400         100        1000           0           0         400
  Columns 15 through 17
     600        1000           0
isequal(B,B0)
ans =
     1
```

Just ensure that `A` is a *row vector*, otherwise transpose the input first (`A=A.';`).

Comment: Thank chappjc. I get it.

Comment: Another thing how can I read the data together with original frame. for example
A = [0 0 0 400 600 1000 1400 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 600 400 100 1000 0 0 0 0 400 600 1000 0 0];
size of A is 1x27 .
this size I consider as frame which is 
A frame is =[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27];
When I run your program, The size(frame) is changing right because of their remove unwanted 0
So how to read data together with their original frame.

Comment: the output should be
B0=[0 400 600 1000 1400 0 0 600 400 100 1000 0 0 400 600 1000 0];
frame for B0=[3 4 5 6 7 8 14 15 16 17 18 19 22 23 24 25 26];

Comment: @danjoro That would be `find(~extraZeros)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the last index of the most repeated number, you can do as follows:

```
% using histc count all numbers
uniqueA = unique(A);
n = histc( A, unique(A) );


% find most repeated number based on hist output
[C,I] = max(n);
mostRepeatedNumber = uniqueA(I(1));

lastIndexOfMostRepeatedNumber = find(A == mostRepeatedNumber, 1, 'last');
```

---

To find index of last zero in a your string you can do the following:

```
zerosInA = A == 0;
lastZeros = find(diff(zerosInA) == -1);
% lastZeros = 3    14    22
% NOTE: it wont detect the last zero. But you can easily check whether last element
% is zero or not, i.e. A(end) == 0.
```

Comment: Thank Marcin for answer. I get it but only the last 0 number. how can I do it in loop. Should be my output is
output:
0 400 600 1000 1400 0      
0 600 400 100 1000 0      
0 400 600 1000 0

Comment: @danjoro I added new example based on your comment. I still don't understand how you generate the output but you can get index of last zeros as you asked for.